# Load CSV into Neo4j and create nodes out of each row with relationship based on similarity?

Tags: neo4j, cypher, neo4j-apoc

I have a CSV source with a large number of columns and I want to build 2 things:

1. Load the CSV to my Neo4j graph and turn every row to a node.
2. Build relationship between nodes based on a cosine similarity (above some threshold alpha).
   Here is what I have already done for (1):

`WITH "https://drive.google.com/u/0/ucid=1FRi5YmWNQJZ2xeTKNO4b12xYGOTWk1jL&export=download" AS data_url`
`LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM data_url AS requests`

But it returns me an error "Query cannot conclude with LOAD CSV (must be RETURN or an update clause)"

Should I transform the data to be in a long format (with data_key and data_value columns) and use the following?:

```
// For each request (request_id), collect it's attributes into key-value pairs
WITH requests.request_id AS request_id,
    COLLECT([requests.data_key, requests.data_value]) AS keyValuePairs
WITH request_id,
     apoc.map.fromPairs(keyValuePairs) AS map

// Each request converts to a node with it's attributes:
MERGE (r:Requests {request_id:request_id})
SET r += map

// Show all nodes:
MATCH (n) RETURN n
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply return the rows with a `RETURN` statement?

```
WITH "https://drive.google.com/u/0/ucid=1FRi5YmWNQJZ2xeTKNO4b12xYGOTWk1jL&export=download" AS data_url LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM data_url AS requests
RETURN * LIMIT 5
```

I don't know what's inside the CSV, but let's assume it's a bunch of various columns with float values. With the `LOAD CSV` you have to manually cast all values to float.

```
WITH "https://drive.google.com/u/0/ucid=1FRi5YmWNQJZ2xeTKNO4b12xYGOTWk1jL&export=download" AS data_url LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM data_url AS requests
CREATE (r:Request)
SET r.data = [toFloat(requests.column1), toFloat(requests.column2)]
```

Notice that I've stored an array of floats as the property.
This is due to the way the kNN algorithm in GDS library works.
Next, it is advisable to use the Graph Data Science library and specifically the [kNearestNeighbor algorithm](https://neo4j.com/docs/graph-data-science/current/algorithms/knn/).
First, you have to project the in-memory graph.

```
CALL gds.graph.create('requests', 'Request', '*', {nodeProperties: ['data']})
```

And then run the knn algorithm, perhaps to write the results back to the database:

```
CALL gds.beta.knn.write('requests', {
  nodeWeightProperty: 'data',
  writeRelationshipType: 'SIMILAR',
  writeProperty: 'score',
  topK: 10
})
```

With the kNN algo, you can't define the similarity threshold, only the topK neighbors. However, you could the the plain cosine similarity algorithm to define the similarity threshold.

```
MATCH (r:Request)
WITH {item:id(r), weights: r.data} AS userData
WITH collect(userData) AS data
CALL gds.alpha.similarity.cosine.write({
  data: data,
  similarityCutoff: 0.5
})
```